# Querying "field" in Outlook RDOMail object

Tags: outlook, outlook-redemption

I have a piece of code that uses DASL queries to query values saved in the user property of items in an RDOFolder, something like this:
`rdoFolder.Items.Find("\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/MyUserPropertyName/0x0000001F\"='queryValue'"`

However, now I need to migrate data saved in my user properties into the `Field` property of RDOMail item. I'd like to know if there's a similar way to query this `Field` property for fast performance. Looping through all items in the folder to do a value comparison could be very slow when there are tens of thousands of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the `RDOFolder.Items.Find` method also searches values saved via the `RDOMail.Fields` index property. Just as what Dmitry said in his comment.

For example, if I set the value like this:

```
myRdoMail.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{8d736f90-8f45-4591-81aa-c85a98f1261b}/MyUserProperty"] = "MyValue";
```

Then I'll be able to find this item by doing the following:

```
var result = myRdoFolder.Items.Find("\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{8d736f90-8f45-4591-81aa-c85a98f1261b}/MyUserProperty\"='MyValue'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the same DASL name to the `RDOMail.Fields` indexed property.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Did you mean that you can do something like this: `rdoMail.Fields["\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{00020329-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/MyUserPropertyName/0x0000001F\"='queryValue'"]`? Even if you can do this, doesn't the code still need to loop through all items in a particular folder and perform the above query on all fields of each item?

Comment: You can do `rdoMail.Fields["http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{‌​00020329-0000-0000-C‌​000-000000000046}/My‌​UserPropertyName/0x0‌​000001F"]`. Since the question is about a particular RDOMail object, yes, it must be opened first. If you want to query multiple items in a single call RDOFolder.Items.Find/FindNext/Restrict or ExecSQL are the way to go.